# Is it possible to process files from a shared network drive with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify

I'm trying to run a simple minification process using gulp. I've done this successfully on local source files on my machine, but what I'm trying to do is target the files on a shared network drive. Basically what I'm doing:

```
gulp.src(_inputPath)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(_outputPath));
```

Where `_inputPath` and `_outputPath` are variables set by a config file:

```
{
    "input": "\\\\drive-name\\home\\project\\js\\*.js",
    "output": "\\\\drive-name\\home\\project\\dist\\"
}
```

The output of files to the network directory works fine (tested by having the input set to a local directory), but I can't seem to get the input to work. What am I doing wrong?]

EDIT:

I'm able to do the following:

```
glob('**/*.js', {cwd:_inputPath}, (err, files) => { if (err) throw err; console.log(files) });
```

And successfully return the files, but trying to use the `cwd` option in `gulp.src` doesn't work:

```
gulp.src('**/*.js', {cwd: _inputPath})
```

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but are all of the .js files at the root of the js folder? Your input argument won't search recursively.

Comment: Yes, all JS files in in the root of `js`